# What is the remaining information in this matrix after applying the quotient?

Tags: linear-algebra

I read this paper written by Alain Connes:
https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.2091
On page 6 we have a matrix C whose elements are inner products in a Hilbert space of two basis.
One is related to an algebra M and the other to another algebra N.
At the bottom of page 6, the author writes,

"In the construction of §2.2, the entries of the matrix C are labeled by the spectra
of M and N. We shall now show how to eliminate the labeling coming from the
spectrum of M. The resulting invariant will give the relative position of M viewed
as a subalgebra of L(H) relative to N viewed as a von Neumann algebra with known
spectrum. In order to eliminate the parameter x ∈ Spec(M) we take ...."
He uses the action of U(N) that gives equivalent matrices (the C matrix multiplied by these unitary matrices of U(N)).
I wonder what is the remaining information in the equivalent classes we get. Connes says that it is information about the "position of M relative to N" . I suppose that he is talking about angles like in the CKM matrix
If we see lines of the C unitaty matrix as vectors and we take the unit sphere S we get n points on it. Is the remaining information about
their relative position on S?